# Filter components by the value of a select element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

Here is a link to my app on Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-search-gxidc?file=/src/App.js it's only one component app.js

In data.js I have an array of objects:

```
export const data = [
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "AFN", name: "Afghan afghani", symbol: "؋" }],
    languages: [
      { iso639_1: "ps", iso639_2: "pus", name: "Pashto", nativeName: "پښتو" },
      { iso639_1: "uz", iso639_2: "uzb", name: "Uzbek", nativeName: "Oʻzbek" },
      {
        iso639_1: "tk",
        iso639_2: "tuk",
        name: "Turkmen",
        nativeName: "Türkmen"
      }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
    name: "Afghanistan",
    topLevelDomain: [".af"],
    capital: "Kabul",
    region: "Asia",
    subregion: "Southern Asia",
    population: 27657145,
    borders: ["IRN", "PAK", "TKM", "UZB", "TJK", "CHN"],
    nativeName: "افغانستان"
  },
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "EUR", name: "Euro", symbol: "€" }],
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: "sv",
        iso639_2: "swe",
        name: "Swedish",
        nativeName: "svenska"
      }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
    name: "Åland Islands",
    topLevelDomain: [".ax"],
    capital: "Mariehamn",
    region: "Europe",
    subregion: "Northern Europe",
    population: 28875,
    borders: [],
    nativeName: "Åland"
  },
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "ALL", name: "Albanian lek", symbol: "L" }],
    languages: [
      { iso639_1: "sq", iso639_2: "sqi", name: "Albanian", nativeName: "Shqip" }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg",
    name: "Albania",
    topLevelDomain: [".al"],
    capital: "Tirana",
    region: "Europe",
    subregion: "Southern Europe",
    population: 2886026,
    borders: ["MNE", "GRC", "MKD", "KOS"],
    nativeName: "Shqipëria"
  },
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "DZD", name: "Algerian dinar", symbol: "د.ج" }],
    languages: [
      { iso639_1: "ar", iso639_2: "ara", name: "Arabic", nativeName: "العربية" }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/dza.svg",
    name: "Algeria",
    topLevelDomain: [".dz"],
    capital: "Algiers",
    region: "Africa",
    subregion: "Northern Africa",
    population: 40400000,
    borders: ["TUN", "LBY", "NER", "ESH", "MRT", "MLI", "MAR"],
    nativeName: "الجزائر"
  },
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "USD", name: "United State Dollar", symbol: "$" }],
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: "en",
        iso639_2: "eng",
        name: "English",
        nativeName: "English"
      },
      {
        iso639_1: "sm",
        iso639_2: "smo",
        name: "Samoan",
        nativeName: "gagana fa'a Samoa"
      }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/asm.svg",
    name: "American Samoa",
    topLevelDomain: [".as"],
    capital: "Pago Pago",
    region: "Oceania",
    subregion: "Polynesia",
    population: 57100,
    borders: [],
    nativeName: "American Samoa"
  },
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "EUR", name: "Euro", symbol: "€" }],
    languages: [
      { iso639_1: "ca", iso639_2: "cat", name: "Catalan", nativeName: "català" }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/and.svg",
    name: "Andorra",
    topLevelDomain: [".ad"],
    capital: "Andorra la Vella",
    region: "Europe",
    subregion: "Southern Europe",
    population: 78014,
    borders: ["FRA", "ESP"],
    nativeName: "Andorra"
  },
  {
    currencies: [{ code: "AOA", name: "Angolan kwanza", symbol: "Kz" }],
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: "pt",
        iso639_2: "por",
        name: "Portuguese",
        nativeName: "Português"
      }
    ],
    flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/ago.svg",
    name: "Angola",
    topLevelDomain: [".ao"],
    capital: "Luanda",
    region: "Africa",
    subregion: "Middle Africa",
    population: 25868000,
    borders: ["COG", "COD", "ZMB", "NAM"],
    nativeName: "Angola"
  }
];
```

I wanna map through it and display information about each country (I did this part ) at app.js

here is the code in app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { data } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  const [cuntries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
    setCountries(data)
  },[])

  function filterByRegion(event) {
    setRegion(event.target.value);
    handleSubmit()
    // event.preventDefault()
  }

  function handleSubmit(){
    const newArr = cuntries.filter(cunt=> cunt.region === region)
    setCountries(newArr)
  }
  

  console.log(region);
  console.log(cuntries);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>filtering</h1>
      <form onChange={filterByRegion}>
      <label>Filter by region:</label>
        <select name="regions" id="region-select" >
          <option value="">Chose a region</option>
          <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
          <option value="Americas">Americas</option>
          <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
          <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
          <option value="Polar">Polar</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <div>
        {cuntries.map((country) => {
          return (
            <div key={country.name} className="country">
              <h3>{country.name}</h3>
              <h3>{country.nativeName}</h3>
              <h3>{country.region}</h3>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In app.js I have a select element that contains regions
I wanna filter the array that I used to render each country So that when I choose a different region the map method render the countries that in this region

I tried some solution but non of them worked.

the link to the app again **https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-search-gxidc?file=/src/App.js:0-1424**

Comment: Some typos in App.js - `cuntries` instead of `countries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem could be `setRegion` is handled asynchronously so once you try to filter further by its value in `handleSubmit` then the value is most probably not there. See down below the suggested modifications on your component.

The first thing is to add `onChange` event to `select` instead of `form`:

```
<select name="regions" id="region-select" onChange={filterByRegion}>
    <option value="">Chose a region</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Americas">Americas</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
    <option value="Polar">Polar</option>
</select>
```

Modify `filterRegion` to pass down the value to `handleSubmit` as:

```
const filterByRegion = (event) => {
    const region = event.target.value

    // I would keep this state if you really need for other purposes
    setRegion(region) 

    handleSubmit(region)
}
```

Then I would use with `.filter` the `data` as the original array to find values as:

```
const handleSubmit = (regionValue) => {
    const newArr = data.filter(c => c.region === regionValue)
    setCountries(newArr)
}
```

Please find the working CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-search-forked-jz4uj?file=/src/App.js).

**+1 addition:**

If you want to render something for no values found state for you countries:

```
{cuntries && cuntries.length > 0 ?
     cuntries.map((country) => {
          return (
            <div key={country.name} className="country">
              <h3>{country.name}</h3>
              <h3>{country.nativeName}</h3>
              <h3>{country.region}</h3>
            </div>
          );
     })
     : <div>No value found</div>
}
```

So if there are no values in your `countries` array you can render a `<div>` which states there are no values found.

Comment: okay, Where should I add the handleSumbit()  function as event listener

Comment: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-search-gxidc?file=/src/App.js) Here is a link with the updates

Comment: @AhmedEldawody See the working modification based on what I was writing here: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-search-forked-jz4uj?file=/src/App.js The dropdown works like charm once you select values.

Comment: I don't wanna be rude, every thing is working just fine. But when I select the first option (Chose a region) Nothing get rendered

Comment: So, can you please help me with that , thank you very much :)

Comment: So what would you expect to be rendered once you have no values? I've added my guess, I guess that's helping to move further with a different solution if you need somehow differently the no values state.

Comment: Thank you Mr/ Norbitrial. I learned a lot from you <3